# Components of contravariant velocity

Tags: calculus, vectors, tensors, classical-mechanics

The question is from Grinfeld's "Tensor Analysis and Calculus of Moving Surfaces" - exercise 81.

QUESTION:

Consider a particle moving along a curve with parameterization with respect to time given by
$$
x^i \equiv x^i(t). 
$$
The velocity is defined as $\vec{v}(t) = \dot{\vec{r}}(t)$. Show that the component $v^i$ of $\vec{v}$ is given by
$$
v^i(t) = \frac{dx^i}{dt}.
$$

ATTEMPT AT SOLUTION:

Defining a covariant basis $\{ \vec{e}_i \} $, we have
$$
\vec{v} = v^i \vec{e}_i = \dot{\vec{r}} = \frac{d}{dt} \left(x^i \vec{e}_i \right) = \dot{x}^i \vec{e}_i + x^i \frac{d\vec{e}_i}{dt}.
$$
At this point, judging from the answer the second term somehow needs to be zero, but I couldn't figure out how. Since the covariant basis is defined by
$$
\vec{e}_i = \frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial x^i},
$$
as we move along the curve the basis vectors are subject to change. So the time derivative $d\vec{e}_i/dt$ may be non-zero. Using the chain rule didn't lead me anywhere:
$$
x^i \frac{d\vec{e}_i}{dt} = x^i \frac{\partial \vec{e}_i}{\partial x^j} \frac{dx^j}{dt} = x^i \dot{x}^j \vec{e}_k \Gamma^k_{ij} = \ldots?
$$
I know I must be missing a very basic point here, would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the issue is that the notation is confusing, and $x$ should be seen as arguments to $R$, but not as component values. That is, $x$ is being used in the $R$ function ($R = R(x)$) and not in the component decomposition $R = R^i e_i \neq x^i e_i$.

This is how I see a solution:

$$ V = \dot{R} = \dot{R}(x) = \frac{\partial R(x)}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial t} = e_i \dot{x}^i $$

Comment: Thanks I think an issue with notation happened here, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could have coordinates that change with time (for instance, a rotating polar coordinate grid in the plane). However, in that case, it's usually easier to introduce a time dimension to your space and have a static coordinate grid on that space (the rotating polar grid will now look like a winding staircase, but stand perfectly still), just like how special and general relativity does.

Which is to say, the entire theory is built on a fixed coordinate grid and fixed coordinate functions. They do not change. As a consequence, the basis vectors do not change either.

Comment: The basis vectors are functions of space - take polar coordinates for instance. As time passes, we move through space on a curve so at any point on that curve the basis vectors may be different. Wouldn't that mean the basis vectors in turn depend on time?

Comment: @ech0_oscar Not really. The basis vectors from point to point are different (are they even in any way comparable?), so as the curve moves through space its tangent vector will be decomposed as a sum of different basis vectors. But the basis vectors _at any point_ are unchanging in time. That's why the second term in your derivative disappears.

Comment: To have a different example, consider a _Cartesian_ grid in the plane, and a point moving vertically at constant speed. Then the components of the velocity won't change. But if the Cartesian grid starts rotating, then suddenly the same movement has a velocity which has changing components. _That_ is your second term.

Comment: What about the chain rule expression written in the last line? Surely there must be a mistake there then right?

Comment: @ech0_oscar The chain rule looks fine. However, as the coordinate functions $x^i$ (not the curve components) are time-independent, $\frac{dx^j}{dt}=0$, and therefore $x^i \frac{\partial \vec{e}_i}{\partial x^j} \frac{dx^j}{dt}=0$.